# previously loaded data of the android listview is hidden in background and exist on empty space

Tags: android, listview, fragment, android-arrayadapter

I have an app with 3 fragments and 3 Custom Array-adapters.

First fragment gets data from the first custom array adapter which contains 3 different row layouts.

Second fragment gets data from second Array-adapter and so on ...

All these three adapters share a class as a data provider which contains set and get methods.

when a user clicks to launch the fragment one for example, list-view gets filled with some specific data which fetched from the database and so on ....

I have activated click listener for each row of the list-view inside all adapters.

The data fills correctly on each fragment, but my problem is that it seems on the empty space of each list-view, there are previously loaded data from previous fragment(s), because I see that row click-listener works on empty spaces and do action based on previously filled data and these filled data are kept and were correct in the previous fragment.

In the other word, if the previous fragment list-view had a longer filled data than the newly loaded fragment, the empty space of the newly loaded fragment fills with previous fragment list-view data, but they are hidden. Just I realize this when I click on the empty space.

I tried everything like clearing the adapter and so on on fragments onCreate but no trick helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. My mistake was I had written the "add" method instead of "replace" to exchange the fragments.